# Gauge Permitting c Magnetic Vector and Instant Electric Scalar Potentials?

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, causality, gauge

The Lorenz gauge requires c propagation of both scalar and vector potentials.  The Coulomb gauge requires instant "propagation" of these potentials but [is stated in such a way as to permit c propagation of the electromagnetic fields](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.6210).

If recent experiments measuring the speed of the Coulomb interaction as instantaneously "propagating", such as "[Measuring Propagation Speed of Coulomb Fields](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.2913)" were widely replicated and accepted, what might, say, a gauge used to calculate electromagnetic waves in the near and far fields (as is the Lorenz gauge now) look like?